# AngularJS two way data binding in directive not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that updates a bound property, but it never seems to update the original property!

```
directives.directive('recordVideo', [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            showRecordVideo: '='
        },
        controller: "recordVideoController as ctrl",
        templateUrl: '/views/recordvideo.html'
    };
}]);

<record-video data-show-record-video="showAddScheduleDialog"></record-video>
```

When I set `$scope.showAddScheduleDialog = true` in the parent controller, the directive sees the change and shows the dialog.  When the dialog itself sets its property `$scope.showRecordVideo = false` the bound property on the parent controller `showAddScheduleDialog` never updates!

Why is this?

I have tried putting `$scope.$watch` on both the parent controller and the directive.  The changes only propogate down to the directive and never back up to the controller!

Comment: Put some JSFIddle to help.

Comment: Please go through [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HarshMehta/6zf6ndtx/). You will get what you are missing currently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by javascript prototype inheritance ([the long answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/5157454)). The usual hack is to change a property inside:

This stays the same:

```
scope: {
    showRecordVideo: '='
},
```

In controller:

```
$scope.showRecordVideo = {
    state: true
};
```

In modal:

```
$scope.showRecordVideo.state = false;
```